# issue while implementing sorting pipe by date

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting, date

I am trying to implement sorting pipe for that I have followed this documentation
 http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1211/angular-2-search-and-sort-with-ngfor-repeater-with-example

and according to that I have created a pipe and imported that pipe in the the component and appended pipe in html

It is sorting by date but not in a proper order though.[[image: unsorted]

[image: sorted]

```js
// component
import { OrderByPipe } from '../../pipes/order-by.pipe';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class SurveyInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  surveyRecords: Array<any>;
  isDesc: boolean = false;
  column: string = "date";
  direction: number;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.surveyRecords = [
      { surveyID: 1, surveyName: "survey1", date: "1-10-2016" },
      { surveyID: 9, surveyName: "survey9", date: "1-12-2016" },
      { surveyID: 3, surveyName: "survey3", date: "9-10-2016" },
      { surveyID: 5, surveyName: "survey5", date: "11-10-2016" },
      { surveyID: 6, surveyName: "survey6", date: "16-10-2016" },
      { surveyID: 7, surveyName: "survey7", date: "19-10-2016" },
      { surveyID: 8, surveyName: "survey8", date: "21-10-2016" },
      { surveyID: 4, surveyName: "survey4", date: "10-10-2016" },
      { surveyID: 10, surveyName: "survey10", date: "1-10-2017" },
      { surveyID: 2, surveyName: "survey2", date: "5-10-2016" },
      { surveyID: 11, surveyName: "survey11", date: "5-10-2017" },
      { surveyID: 12, surveyName: "survey12", date: "15-10-2017" },
      { surveyID: 13, surveyName: "survey13", date: "25-10-2017" }
    ];
  }

  sort(property) {
    console.log(property);
    this.isDesc = !this.isDesc; //change the direction
    this.column = property;
    this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
  }
}

//pipe
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(surveyRecords: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
  //  return null;
  console.log(surveyRecords);
     return surveyRecords.sort(function(a, b) {
      a['date']= Date.parse(a['date']);
      b['date']= Date.parse(b['date']);
       if (a[args.property] < b[args.property]) {
         
         return -1 * args.direction;
       } else if (a[args.property] > b[args.property]) {
         return 1 * args.direction;
       } else {
         return 0;
       }
     });
  }

}
```

```html
<mat-nav-list class="surveys">
  <strong class="survey-list">Surveys
    <span>

       <mat-icon (click)="sort('date')" >arrow_downward </mat-icon>
     
    </span>
   
  </strong>

  <a mat-list-item  *ngFor="let survey of surveyRecords|orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}"> {{ survey.surveyName }} </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: your date is a "string" and is not 'yyyy-MM-dd", so you must to convert to Date() object whith parseDate or split by '-' and reorder before sort. "31-10-1900">"01-05-2017"